# How to set input criteria on android form

Tags: android, textbox, validation

I have very simple question. In my application I have some TextEdit fields. I want the user to fill all the TextEdit fields and then click on finish button. But after the finish button is pressed I want to check the validity of input text in TextEdit boxes.

1. How to check the input is a valid email id?
2. How to check the input is a valid phone number?
3. How to check a password entered is of length 4 and contains specific characters only?

Is there any in-built feature to do all these in SDK or I need to code myself. If I need to do by myself can anybody suggest what I need to do for accomplishing the above task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ::

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".* (Ka).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Manoj Kumar Kashyap");
if(matcher.matches())
{
    int idx = matcher.start(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `EditText`'s `inputType` attribute, and it will help you a little by disallowing entering invalid values and displaying the proper softkeyboard if applicable. Ultimately you will have to get the values of those fields, and check them manually the old fashion way (for instance, your password field).